# How to convert single quote into double quote in jinja template file?

Tags: json, templates, jinja2, salt-stack

Hi I have a salt state file who has a ".sls" extension and it is using jinja template

There I am creating a list in jinja template. Problem is when I run that file then list converts into JSON which convert double quotation around each element into single quotation which causes error.

```
{%- set opentsdb_hosts = [] -%}
{%- for host in salt['pnda.opentsdb_hosts']() -%}
{%- do opentsdb_hosts.append("http://%s:%s" % (host, opentsdb_port)) -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

As you can see, I am creating a list whose name is **opentsdb_hosts**. Each element inside **opentsdb_hosts** should have a double quotation around. But it is doing single quotation.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You must be outputting `opentsdb_hosts` directly using `{{ opentsdb_hosts }}`, which outputs it in a python-friendly format, one that usually prefers single quotes over double quotes (although both quotation marks work in python as valid string literals).

To output `opentsdb_hosts` as json, simply use the json renderer provided by salt instead, i.e. `{{ opentsdb_hosts | tojson }}`.

Answer (score -1):

You may use this `regex_replace("'", '"')` to replace the single quote with double quotes

Comment: Is it necessary to rely on Regex in this case?

Comment: @JeremyCaney Not mandatory, but this is an easy solution to use along with the Jinja template(solution according to this particular query/scenario)